# Comparing 2 text files, and exporting the lines that don't exists in file no.1

Tags: c#, text

Basically what I need to do is so:

```
File no.1:
1
2    
4    
5    
51    
21

File no.2:
31
21
4

What should be exported:
1
2
5
51
```

Basically only export the lines that do not exist in the second text.

My current attempt:

```
bool exists = false;
string[] lines1 = File.ReadAllLines("path1");
string[] lines2 = File.ReadAllLines("path2");

for (int i = 0; i < lines1.Length; i++)
{
    for (int g = 0; g < lines2.Length; g++)
    {
        if (lines1[i] == lines2[g])
        {
            exists = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Exists!");
            break;
        }                   
    }
    if (!exists)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(lines1[i]);
        exists = false;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("End of file reached");
Console.ReadLine();
```

I feel like there is a proper function for me to use, although this is what i came up with, thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want also 5 in the result?

Comment: @FrancescoB. haha! you are right that was my bad :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your desired result you can use LINQ and [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method. Like this:

```
string[] result = lines1.Except(lines2).ToArray();
```

Comment: Wow! well, that just made my attempt pretty pathetic. thank you very much and have a nice day :)

Comment: This solution can be improved by reading the source file string arrays with `File.ReadLines` instead of `File.ReadAllLines`.

Answer (score 1):

In general case, if `file2` can contain *duplicates* which you want to preserve, I suggest using `HashSet<string>`:

```
 HashSet<string> toSkip = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadLines(path1));

 var toExport = File
   .ReadLines(path2)
   .Where(line => !toSkip.Contains(line));
 //.ToArray(); // <- if you want to materialize the final result

 // Test
 foreach (var item in toExport)
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```